# To Run an sql script only one time before executing Spring boot JUnit Class

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, junit4

I am Trying to execute an Sql file which may contain any CRUD operation(s) before executing a Spring boot Junit class/ regression Test Suite. I did it using typical/legacy JDBC way, but want to use latest API. JDBC template won't help here it seems as i am trying to run the Script. Please help me here.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is to pre-seed your database prior running tests. For this I usually use one of two strategies.

1. You can put a file called `data.sql` into your `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` folder. Spring Boot will automatically pick it up and import the data into your database. If you only want to import a schema you can use `schema.sql` as an alternative.
2. If you want specific data and schema loaded for tests you can always also use the `@Sql` annotation for that. It allows you to specify a list of SQL files to be run prior running your tests.

```java
@Sql({"/employee_schema.sql", "/employee_test_data.sql"})
public class EmployeeTest {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
 
    @Test
    public void testLoadDataForTestClass() {
        assertEquals(3, employeeRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

I usually refer to this excellent tutorial:

- [Quick Guide on Loading Initial Data with Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql)

Comment: Is it possible to run an @SQL script for just a few tests? Something like "execute this SQL only for test a, b, c and d.

My goal is not to have all my tests in a certain test class be based on the same data set. From experience, I know that in the long run, this can lead to problems (e.g. changing the value of a field in a record or adding a new record can break N tests)

Comment: @Marco If I understood your question correctly, yes you can. Just use the `@Sql` annotation above the test method that you want to run.

Comment: Using @Sql along with `@Nested` class I achieved the result.
Thank you, Nigel